# Obtaining windows menu from the dock with a quick click

Tags: dock

In OS X (and in Mountain Lion, in particular) when you minimize a window and you want to retrieve it, you can press on an icon in the dock and wait 1 second to get the menu with the opened windows. Is it possible to change this setting so that this menu opens on a mouse click immediately (preferably, the menu would appear when there is more than one window and, as it is currently, the click maximizes the minimized window if there is only one window instance of that program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean this menu

[image]

you can show it immediately by just secondary-clicking (which usually means right-clicking) the Dock icon.